# exclusively apply java pattern matcher to extract html elements, ignore some characters

Tags: java, html, regex, pattern-matching

I'm using this code:

```
Pattern pat_1 = Pattern.compile("class=\"\"pinyin\"\">(.*?)<script>");
Matcher mat_1 = pat_1.matcher( text );
while( mat_1.find() )
{
    System.out.println( mat_1.group(1) );
}
```

This is the input data source bring matched:

```
<br>
<span class=""b"">拼音：</span><span class=""pinyin"">xī<script>Setduyin('Duyin/xi1')</script></span>　<span class=""b"">注音：</span><span class=""pinyin"">ㄒㄧ<script>Setduyin('Duyin/xi1')</script></span><br>
<span class=""b"">简体部首：</span>丨　<span class=""b"">部首笔画：</span>1　<span class=""b"">总笔画：</span>8<br><span class=""b"">繁体部首：</span>卜　<span class=""b"">部首笔画：</span>2　<span class=""b"">总笔画：</span>8<br><span class=""b"">康熙字典笔画</span>( 卥:8； )
```

The problem with my code is that it also picks up `ㄒㄧ` because the preceding and proceding elements are identical. How could I exclude `ㄒㄧ` and only select `xī`. maybe I can use the `<br>` tag because that is something unique to the first once, but that necessitates identifying a new line and also ignoring `拼音：` how to do that? I've been playing around with regex101.com but I've not yet been able to pin it down.

So to be clear right now the output of that java code is

```
xī
ㄒㄧ
```

but I want it only to be

```
xī
```

Comment: Avoid parsing HTML with a regex. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752487/4125191) if you want to understand why. You also didn't specify what makes "TI" bad. What happens if you have "ABC" or something like that?

Comment: Do you need the extraction of strings not being "ㄒㄧ" only in this particular relative arrangement? (xi (or yi or...) before T-?) Or could the sequence also be "T-", "xi", "yi", "T-"?

Comment: What do you mean "the text that comes just after that `</span>`? EVerything to the end of the string?

Comment: @Yamada please don't update your question 5 mins after posting.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the whole reason I'm doing it this way is that XPath failed me. I originally tried very hard to extract these elements with XPath but nothing worked.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I see that is bad, I'll refrain from it in future

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you show a reference why that is not allowed? Usually we *ask* the users to update their questions to improve them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic edit within 5 mins grace period won't be a matter. First i answered his real question. And op says that it's working. So i moved on to the next question. After sometime, i received a downvote that op updated his question yours won't work. It's like a kind of ****

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think because my update was highly tangential of original topic

Comment: @AvinashRaj who downvote you? I upvote you and accept your answer. sorry to cause you a frustration.

Comment: No one has the power to find the downvoter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
Pattern pat_1 = Pattern.compile("class=\"\"pinyin\"\">(.*?)<script>(?:(?!<script>).)*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gL0jQ3/4)

**OR**

```
(?m)^.*?class=\"\"pinyin\"\">(.*?)<script>
```

`(?m)` called multiline modifier, it's safe to enable this modifier when anchors `^`, `$` are used in the regex.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gL0jQ3/5)

Comment: incredible--> exactly perfect. so this mean ignore (?:

Comment: @laune what do you mean by that?

Comment: but the data won't have that, "T-" will always come after "xi"

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō Then why do you use "while"??? A simple if will get you the xi! Or can there be multiple "xi" before the "T-"???

Comment: because there are many many datas, all have the same structure i want all the equivalents of 'xi' maybe next one is 'yi' but still it will be before "T/" do you know what I mean?

Comment: Exactly one xi or yi or zi before the one "T-"? Then use if! Not while!

Comment: @laune you're helping me to see that and improve myself. thank you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have tried a modified text with "xi"-"xi"-"T-" and "T-"-"xi"-"T-", with your pattern, not knowing that the task is simply to extract *only the first text string* between pinyin and script. I'll remove my answer, cancel your downvote (although no complex regexes are required) and downvote the Q.